# MongoDB with same throughput

Tags: mongodb, performance, ycsb, nosql

I'm testing mongodb starting with one node, then 2 datanodes (1 master, 1 config-server and 2 masters), then 4 datanodes (1 master, 1 config-server, 4 masters) and with 16 datanodes (same configuration as before with 16 masters). I noticed the throughput is the same indipendently from the number of nodes: with 30 threads (using YCSB) I obtained about 6000 ops/sec with 2, 4 or 16 nodes!!
It's normal? Or there are some parameters to set??

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: I take it your are talking about sharding here? Were the data nodes replica sets or were they standalone? Also what shard key was used and what distribution was it?

Comment: every master is on its own replica-set and every node belong to a different shard (simply I have 16 nodes belong to 16 shards). I have data like: userXXXXXXXXXXXXXX with XXXXX... a number from 000000000000001 to 9999999999999 and I'm using this parameter, which is the id, as shard key. I hope to respond at all :P

Comment: Ok that might be a bad shard key to begin with, but still even with that bad shard key that could have sent most of your OPs to a single machine you should get over 6k OPs. What was the distribution of the OPs as well? How many reads/writes what amount inserts/updates etc? I cna tell you should be able to get better OPs, also for these threads how many mongos instances were you using?

Comment: I have only one mongos, because the benchmark I'm using permits me to connect only to one host (so one mongo). Also I read on mongo's manual to use one mongos for every application, and I'm testing a single application. I try with something like 1 million of operation, 50% update and 50% read

Comment: Where does it say to use only one mongos per application? I would be interested in filing a bug report for that, in reality you should try to have many mongos per application, a mongos in itself only handle so many connections over such a distributed space so if you are struggling with capacity it might be that you need more capacity in your mongos

Comment: It is normally said that one mongos per application server is good enough, but that also depends on how many connections that server gets

Comment: Well, I continue with only one mongos because the utilization of the cpu of the mongos server doesn't reach more than 80%, it's not saturated! Also the utilization of the datanodes (the masters) is never saturated!

Comment: Nah a mongos should never use much CPU (unless your doing aggregation framework in it then it can use some CPU) but it can be fully loaded with connections while the server is still pretty much idle.

Comment: But the lowest ops per second I have seen with one mongos on a benchmark is 10K so I am unsure why you are getting, 6k it is scratching my head a little

Comment: I load something like 1/1.5 million of records (composed by userXXX, each ones has from field1 to field10), on amazon ec2 machines with 2 cpu, 7.5Gb RAM. I take mongo as it is, launch mongod on each datanode, set replSet for each datanode, start a configserver and start a mongos server which is in charge to add all the nodes to ifferent shard (so I have 16 differents master). This is what I've done. I test it with 50% update operations and 50% read, with a zipfian distribution and with the client using 4, 8, 16 or 30 threads. I run the test 20 times, and the average ops/sec is about 6500

Comment: how many threads are you specifying for YCSB run?  Also please use https://github.com/achille/YCSB instead of the old distro - that was never updated to use the mongodb java driver optimally.

Comment: I test the database with different run, each for a different number of threads: I noticed that I saturate the mongos with 16 and 30 threads, so I'm trying to test everything with more than one mongos. It is normal that a mongos instance saturate so early? I will try with achille YCSB, hoping it use the same entry data as the old one!

Comment: Also (sorry for double comment) when I try to test mongodb with four mongos and four mongod, always with one config server, it seems to have a very random performance. I connect to every mongos with a different client and sometimes all mongos instances work, sometimes only two: it seems that some mongos redirect its workload to another mongos! Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a non balanced shard configuration based on the value of the keys. This shard key isn't likely optimal with YCSB:

`shard key: { "_id" : 1 }`

You may instead want to try hash sharding like:

`shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }`

One way you can tell is to run mongostat on each shard and see if you are getting a nice spread of OPS.  If not, then iterate on shard keys until you do.  YCSB may need to be altered with this in mind.

Comment: I'll try  this! Indeed the cpu utilization of the 16 nodes is very low (about 20%). My bottleneck is mongos, but I'd prefer to use only one because I'm testing other databases all with one single client. I'm testing it like this just to see this properties!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add more mongos on the network. So now I have 4 mongod and 4 mongos. I connect to each mongos with a different client, but it seems that one mongos works really hard, the second one works but not so hard and the other two doesn't work at all (cpu utilization is around 10%). My question is, how mongos' work? I mean, the mongos cluster decide wich mongos has to manage the load/connection? If I connect from a client to a mongos, it could happen that mongos redirect the request to another mongos? Thanks!